# Buster.js dependency error with jQuery: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, buster.js

Whenever I attempt to run my unit tests (written with buster and executed user `buster test`) and include jQuery (since my library depends on it). I get the following error:

`./test/deps/jquery-1.7.2.min.js: window is not defined`

Here's my buster.js config file:
var config = module.exports;

```
config["GitJs Tests"] = {
    rootPath: "../",
    environment: "node",
    sources: [
        "src/Gitjs.js"
    ],
    deps: [
        "test/deps/*.js" // Jquery is in here
    ],
    tests: [
        "test/test_constructor.js"
    ]
};
```

Why do I get this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some digging and figured out that you get this error because, when running in Node, *there is no window*. jQuery requires the `window` object to work properly.

In short: you can't use jQuery in NodeJs (at least not in its native format :D). If you want to use jQuery and busterJs, you need to run it in "browser" mode.